# Error Message: Psych::SyntaxError: (<unknown>): did not find expected key while parsing a block mapping at line 3 column 1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Book: Agile Web Development with rails 5.1

I am running a simple code:  bin/rails test on cli. The output is as follows; 0 failures - 7 errors.

I have run the code through - https://yamlchecker.com.  I have no problems within the code. However, I continue to get the same errors when I run the bin/rails test.  I am following the book example to learn ruby on rails.

```
require 'test_helper'

class ProductsControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
setup do
@product = products(:one)
end

test "should get index" do
get products_url
assert_response :success
end

test "should get new" do
get new_product_url
assert_response :success
end

test "should create product" do
assert_difference('Product.count') do
  post products_url, params:{ 
    product:{
      title: @product.title, 
      description: @product.description, 
      image_url: @product.image_url, 
      price: @product.price 
    } 
  }
end
assert_redirected_to product_url(Product.last)
end

test "should show product" do
get product_url(@product)
assert_response :success
end

test "should get edit" do
get edit_product_url(@product)
assert_response :success
end

test "should update product" do
patch product_url(@product), params:{ 
  product:{
    title: @product.title, 
    description: @product.description, 
    image_url: @product.image_url, 
    price: @product.price 
  } 
}
assert_redirected_to product_url(@product)
end

test "should destroy product" do
assert_difference('Product.count', -1) do
  delete product_url(@product)
end

assert_redirected_to products_url
end
end
```

[Command Line Errors Messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cBo0Y.png)

[Top part of code - sublime text 3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cA88i.png)

[Bottom part of code - sublime text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XTLiH.png)

I am looking for 0 failures and 0 errors. Actual results: 0 failures and 7 errors. all from this file.

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use tabulation on your yaml file. Instead use 4 spaces or check the configuration of your `tab` button.